# ¿Cómo puedo generar ejecutable con cx-Freeze?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo problemas generar el ejecutable con este archivo:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,50,50)
```

Aplicadole este código en el prompt de windows:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


septup (name = "ventana",
       version = "0.1",
       description = "ventana"
       executables = [Executable("rectangulo.py")],)
```

El problema es que no se ejecuta y me genera el siguiente error segun la  imágen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentantado con diferentes opciones y no he logrado ejecutarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente te falta una coma después de `description = "ventana"`. Cada argumento pasado a septup debe estar separado por una coma como en cualquier función:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


septup (name = "ventana",
       version = "0.1",
       description = "ventana",#<<<<<<<<<<<<<
       executables = [Executable("rectangulo.py")],)
```

Esto ocasiona un error de sintaxis como te ocurre a ti.